# java UIManager defaults

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, uimanager

I've been working on a custom themed UI using the UIManager to style my frames, but I'm stuck trying to figure out what I need to do in order to get this border looking proper.

Custom UI

[image: Custom UI]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need, as well as create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @IvanPronin sorry bro will re specify in a minute just had to cut it short going to the gym